# Choppy Animation

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I have the start of a simple game, but the movement of my character across the screen is slightly choppy. The are also distortions like mouth appearing to curve. My terminal says I have at least 60 FPS.

I have included a gif where you can see this behavior

[image]

Are there any modifications I can do to my code to fix this problem?

```
void init() {
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}

void player::moveplayer(){
    pt1=get_time();
    float dt=pt1-pt2;
    pt2=pt1;

    t1 = get_time();
    frames = frames + 1;
    if ((t1 - t2) > 1000.0)
    {
      cout << "FPS "<<frames << endl;
      t2 = t1;
      frames=0;
    }

    if(but[0]){//a
      p_vel[0] = p_vel[0] - 0.5*p_acel*dt*dt;   //apply acceleration
      if(p_vel[0] < -1*p_vterm) p_vel[0] = -1*p_vterm; //terminal v
    }
    if(but[1]){//w
      p_vel[1] = p_vel[1] + 0.5*p_acel*dt*dt;   //apply acceleration
      if(p_vel[1] > p_vterm) p_vel[1] = p_vterm; //terminal v
    }
    if(but[2]){//d
      p_vel[0] = p_vel[0] + 0.5*p_acel*dt*dt;   //apply acceleration
      if(p_vel[0] > p_vterm) p_vel[0] = p_vterm; //terminal v
    }
    if(but[3]){//s
      p_vel[1] = p_vel[1] - 0.5*p_acel*dt*dt;   //apply acceleration
      if(p_vel[1] < -1*p_vterm) p_vel[1] = -1*p_vterm; //terminal v
    }

    //normalize vector
    float mag = sqrt(p_vel[0]*p_vel[0] + p_vel[1]*p_vel[1]);
    if(mag > p_vterm){
      p_vel[0] = p_vterm*p_vel[0]/mag;
      p_vel[1] = p_vterm*p_vel[1]/mag;
    }

    // update positions
    p_pos[0] = p_pos[0] + p_vel[0]*dt;
    //check collisions
    solid_collide(true,false,dt);
    p_pos[1] = p_pos[1] + p_vel[1]*dt;
    //check collisions
    solid_collide(false,true,dt);

    if(fabs(p_vel[0]) < 0.9*p_acel*dt*dt) p_vel[0] = 0.0;
    if(fabs(p_vel[1]) < 0.9*p_acel*dt*dt) p_vel[1] = 0.0;
}

void player::drawplayer(){

   glLoadIdentity();
   if(!loaded){
      playerid[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("../textures/player/head.tga",SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
      loaded=true;
   }

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, playerid[0]);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glTranslatef(p_pos[0], p_pos[1], 0.0f);
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   // Head    
   //Lower Triangle
   glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
   glVertex3f(0.5*p_head,  0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//top right
   glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
   glVertex3f(0.5*p_head, -0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//bottom right
   glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
   glVertex3f(-0.5*p_head, -0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//bottom left
   //Upper Triangle
   glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
   glVertex3f(0.5*p_head,  0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//top right
   glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
   glVertex3f(-0.5*p_head, 0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//top left
   glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
   glVertex3f(-0.5*p_head, -0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//bottom left

   // Body
   //Lower Triangle
   glVertex3f(0.5*p_body,  -0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//top right
   glVertex3f(0.5*p_body, -1*p_body-0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//bottom right
   glVertex3f(-0.5*p_body, -1*p_body-0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//bottom left
   //Upper Triangle
   glVertex3f(0.5*p_body,  -0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//top right
   glVertex3f(-0.5*p_body, -0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//top left
   glVertex3f(-0.5*p_body, -1*p_body-0.5*p_head, 0.0f);//bottom left

   glEnd();

}
```

Here is the game loop in my main.cpp

```
void update(int value) {
    play1.moveplayer();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(TIMER_MS, update, 0);//Tell GLUT to call update again 
}


void draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    troom.drawroom();
    play1.drawplayer();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    srand((unsigned int)time(0)); //Seed the random number generator
//        time2 = get_time();


    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);

    glutCreateWindow("A Game");
        init();

    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(press);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(release);
    glutSpecialFunc (spress);
    glutSpecialUpFunc (srelease);
    glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
    glutTimerFunc(TIMER_MS, update, 0); //Add a timer

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use old style OPENGL (in contrast to modern OPENGL). I see it right away because you have no 5k lines of boiler plate code ;)

Comment: Is p_acel a constant? If not, can it be negative? That could cause issue with your if(p_vel[0] < -1*p_vterm) p_vel[0] = -1*p_vterm; statements. Possibly better to remove those if statements, and do this after querying all buttons (for x & y obviously!)

p_vel[0] = std::min(std::max(p_vel[0], -p_vterm), p_vterm);

Comment: Hi @robthebloke p_acel is not a constant, but currently is untouched after being assigned a positive value. Thanks for the suggestion I have updated my code. It doesn't solve the problem. Regardless it's definitely an improvement.

Comment: Can you show us your "game loop", where you call your movePlayer and drawPlayer

Comment: Hi @DraykoonD I have included the game loop from my main.cpp. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: did you tru to move your update method inside your draw method ? it's like you draw some state that are set at non fixed interval